# Django model overwrites a record on my database instead of adding a new one

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now=True)

    def save(self): # ALL the signature
        super(myModel, self).save()
```

And from a view, i'm trying to save some data to my database:

```
model = myModel()
model.user = request.user
model.amount = amount
```

When i open my database, i only see one record. Every time i try to add a new record, that record is overwritten with a new one. Instead, there should be one record every time i add some data, of course. Can someone help me find what am i doing wrong, please?

Comment: that's because you are login in with one user, try to login with another user and see

Comment: Yes, of course, but one user should be able to submit more records, i don't need to overwrite them

Comment: the foreign key is like one to one relation, one records for user I guess , I think you can try many to many relation

Comment: @Jack022 have you tried `create()` method which I mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create record please use `create()` as below...

```
new_obj = myModel.objects.create(user=request.user, amount=amount)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I tried this but i got: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Comment: might be you hve to Remove `save()` method rom `myModel`

Comment: And no need to save object after use `create()`, it will automatically `save` your object into `myModel`.

Comment: Ok! Let me try!

Comment: It's Great, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you! Happy coding too!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
```

remove null and blank from the user field

Comment: Tried this but i got the same output